# Statistical test to use for study where answers are correct or incorrect

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, equivalence

I have data from a study where participants saw an image and were supposed to judge whether it was an AI generated image or not. The Hypothesis I want to test is if they actually are able to differentiate between AI and human, where my prediction is that they can not really.

My question now is what test I could use for this and what data *exactly* I should test on. I have tried reading up on equivalence (TOST) tests, chi-quared tests and standard t-tests but I am completely lost which is the correct one to use in my situation and if I should compare the actual "Value" of the image (i.e. if it is AI or not) to the answers, or if I should somehow do something with the number of correctly determined pictures or compare the results against randomly generated data or maybe I am missing the correct option entirely.

Comment: This may help:  http://staff.washington.edu/tabrooks/599.course/BadChiSquare.html
TL;DR - t-test.  Convert your data to number of correct answers per participant and compare the mean number of correct answers to the expected number correct.  The expected number correct would be 50% of the  number of images, as your hypothesis is they cannot tell the diffeence and are those only guessing.

Comment: Your approach may depend on whether you are looking at whether people in general can/cannot distinguish (a null hypothesis that there is an overall accuracy of 50%) or whether individuals can/cannot (if each person has the same sample size then a null hypothesis that there is a binomial distribution with $p=\frac12$)